# How to add text inside the doughnut chart using Chart.js AngularJS 2.0?

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

```
        <p-chart id="first" *ngIf="!loading && total > 0"
                 height="200" type="doughnut" [data]="dataForActiveInactive" [options]="chartOptions"></p-chart>
```

How to add the text inside the doughnut? There are some code samples here but they don't work for AngularJS 2.0.

I'm using PrimeNG for AngularJS 2.0 which uses ChartJS under the hood: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/doughnut

I've tried setting the animation object inline but didn't work:

```
animation="{onAnimationComplete: function () {alert('animation complete');}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, perhaps not ideally, but solved it.

Register a plugin that enables the tooltips to remain up, then call the plugin from the options.

Include a script file under where you imported chart.js in your index.html with the following code in it:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeRender: function (chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {

        chart.pluginTooltips = [];
        chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                    _chart: chart.chart,
                    _chartInstance: chart,
                    _data: chart.data,
                    _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                   _active: [sector]
                }, chart));
            });
        });

        chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
},
  afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
        if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
            if (easing !== 1)
                return;
            chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
        }

        chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
        Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
            tooltip.initialize();
            tooltip.update();
            tooltip.pivot();
            tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
        });
        chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Then in the options of your chart, include:

```
options: {
    showAllTooltips: true
}
```

For extra points, you can include it in your app.component.ts, underneath/outside the class however you need to declare Chart with `declare var Chart:any;`